# iPhone SDK: How to know when background task has completed?

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0

We are trying to get a background task working for the purpose of including an activity indicator in a workhouse screen. From our understanding, this requires one to create a background thread to run it on. I also understand that no GUI updates can be performed on the background thread.

Given that, here is the general pattern of what needs to happen.

a.) Pre-validate fields. Make sure user did not enter any invalid data
b.) Setup background task. 
c.) Process results from background task

This is what it looks like in code so far:

```
-(IBAction)launchtask:(id)sender 
{
    //validate fields
    [self validateFields];

    /* Operation Queue init (autorelease) */
    NSOperationQueue *queue = [NSOperationQueue new];

    /* Create our NSInvocationOperation to call loadDataWithOperation, passing in nil */
    NSInvocationOperation *operation = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                                                            selector:@selector(backgroundTask)
                                                                              object:nil];

    /* Add the operation to the queue */
    [queue addOperation:operation];
    [operation release];


    //TO DO: Add any post processing code here, BUT how do we know when it is done???
    ConfirmationViewController *otherVC;

    //show confirm
    //if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
    //{
    //  otherVC = [[ConfirmationViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ConfirmationViewPad" bundle:nil];
    //}
    //else
    {
        otherVC = [[ConfirmationViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ConfirmationView" bundle:nil];
    }

    //TO DO: Let's put this in a struct
    otherVC.strConfirmation = strResponse;
    otherVC.strCardType = strCardType;
    otherVC.strCardNumber = txtCardNumber.text;
    otherVC.strExpires = txtExpires.text;
    otherVC.strCustomerEmail = txtEmail.text;

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:otherVC animated:YES];
    [otherVC release];
    otherVC = nil;  


}
```

So far, that works pretty well except that we don't yet have a way to know when the background task is complete. Only when it is complete, can we process the results of the background task. Right now, it doesn't work because there is not synchronization to the two. How to solve?

One other thing, noticed that a spinner is now displayed in the status bar. That is a good thing but it doesn't seem to be going away after the background task has completed? What to do?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your options are, briefly:

- key value observe the 'operationCount' property on NSOperationQueue and wait for it to reach 0 (or, equivalently, the 'operations' property and check the count)
- have your operations fire off a little notification that they're done (probably on the main thread with performSelectorOnMainThread:...) and wait until the correct number of notifications have been received.

[EDIT: I see you've asked specifically about the old SDK 3.0. In that case, observe operations and check count because the operationCount property postdates SDK 3.0]

There's no automatic system for starting and stopping a spinner in the general case. You'll have to talk to it yourself. However, a neat thing about a spinner is that it continues spinning even if the main thread is blocked, so if you're thread hopping just for that purpose then you don't actually need to.

A spinner appears in the status bar to show data fetches, I believe. If it continues spinning then you still have URL requests ongoing, whether or not you're actually waiting for the results.

Comment: Thank you. I tried the KVO method using this code here. http://efreedom.com/Question/1-1049001/Get-Notification-NSOperationQueue-Finishes-Tasks I do get get notification that the operation completed BUT it errs out with this. bool _WebTryThreadLock(bool), 0x885ac40: Tried to obtain the web lock from a thread other than the main thread or the web thread. This may be a result of calling to UIKit from a secondary thread. Crashing now... If it makes any difference in the background thread I am making a synchronous ASIHTTPRequest call.

Comment: What are you doing when you get the KVO notification? Are you doing anything UIKit there?